# How to use DataOnlyExcelFormatOptions to export Crystal report to excel

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export a Crystal Report with the DataOnlyExcelFormatOptions option. But I stuck, the help is too pour and no running example available.

If I use the ExcelFormatOption with the default option, the column order is completely messed up. From the DataOnlyExcelFormatOptions, the attribute might be interesting. But I am unable to find a running solution in VB.

any help is truly appreciated 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to go through the items [here](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/microsoft/reporting-services/416-blank-columns-issue-when-exporting-to-excel-data-only-from-crystal-reports.html). It addresses blank columns, but has some good general points to follow if you're having trouble.

When exporting, it's best to have the most sparse report possible; limit it to the fewest sections, remove as much formatting as you can, and keep the fields lined up, snapped to a grid, and not overlapping. You can also try separating the fields out horizontally with large spaces in between and/or trying a fixed width column.

If you have specific details about what it means to be "completely messed up," that would help nail down some other things to try. Screenshots are helpful too.

Comment: thanks for your message. I forget to say that I am trying to generate the excel document in asp with VB. The data is left aligned, and empty fields are replaced with the right column data, which is really bad.

Comment: @Olivier CR gives you the option of replacing NULLs with a datatype default; is that an option for you?